# A Simple Document creating software, with export options of PDF..?

Tags: documentation-generator, pdf-editor

I have checked Word, and other PDF creating software like PDF Element, Foxit, Adobe.. etc..
but they were difficult to use, and bloated..
I want something Simple and Easy as [QUIP](https://quip.com/) - software, or Google Docx
I need Features in this images, and smooth as QUIP
[image]
Features Wanted - text colour, highligh colour, and bullet format.

Comment: If you already have a preferred editor that doesn’t save as PDF but supports printing on Windows, you could use a print-to-PDF driver such as [LEADTOOLS ePrint Pro]( https://www.eprintdriver.com/Download). (Disclosure: it’s our product). Whenever you wish to export to PDF, you simply issue a Print command, and the driver converts the output to PDF.

Answer (score 1):

Most “simple” editors cannot save as pdf.

You can check LibreOffice Writer - https://www.libreoffice.org/discover/writer/ .It is a powerful tool, but the view can be customized with only required features.